# How can we get GCP Project ID on AI Platform Training?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-training

I want to get my GCP Project ID on AI Platform.
I tried to

- use [metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata)
- run `gcloud config get-value project`

but, AI Platform instance seems to work outside my GCP Project.

Comment: AI Platform Training runs your workload in a different project. Which project id do you need to get? If it's your own project id, then you can get it locally. For instance, you can run 'gcloud config list' to get your project id.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to pass `--project $PROJECT_ID` as an application parameter when you launch the job ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/training-jobs#submit-job)). As an example based on [this sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ai-platform-samples/blob/master/training/tensorflow/structured/base/scripts/train-cloud.sh):

```sh
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training ${JOB_NAME} \
        --stream-logs \
        # more job configuration parameters...
        --config=./config.yaml \
        -- \
        --project=${PROJECT_ID} \
        # more application parameters...
        --num-layers=3
```

Then, in [`task.py`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ai-platform-samples/blob/master/training/tensorflow/structured/base/trainer/task.py) (or file defined in `--module-name`) you can add:

```py
args_parser.add_argument(
    '--project',
    help='Service Project ID where ML jobs are launched.',
    required=True)
```

and then simply access it with `args.project`:

```py
logging.info('Project ID: {}'.format(args.project))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running below command:

```
from google.cloud import aiplatform

aiplatform.init(
    # your Google Cloud Project ID or number
    # environment default used is not set
    project='my-project',

    # the Vertex AI region you will use
    # defaults to us-central1
    location='us-central1',

    # Google Cloud Storage bucket in same region as location
    # used to stage artifacts
    staging_bucket='gs://my_staging_bucket',

    # custom google.auth.credentials.Credentials
    # environment default credentials used if not set
    credentials=my_credentials,

    # customer managed encryption key resource name
    # will be applied to all Vertex AI resources if set
    encryption_spec_key_name=my_encryption_key_name,

    # the name of the experiment to use to track
    # logged metrics and parameters
    experiment='my-experiment',

    # description of the experiment above
    experiment_description='my experiment description'
)
```